# Identifying teeth area within a mouth region in an image

Tags: colors, image-manipulation, detection

I am trying to do an image manipulation wherein the user would be prompted to enclose the mouth portion within an image. Once the user does that my application should identify the pixels that would identify the teeth (the color varying from white to yellow) and then I would like to brighten only those pixel. Could anyone give me a guidance on how to proceed?

Comment: You would have to ask this months after that one tutorial I read on auto-correcting eyes.  It is on http://www.codeproject.com/ and was in, I believe c#.  I'll see if I can drag up a link to it for you.

Comment: There are so many example projects that apply to your needs on that site, you should check some of them out.  Plus side, it isn't just dedicated to one language.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite honestly, very broad as an adequate answer will touch on a large number of areas.

Nevertheless, what you are trying to attempt is called [Pattern Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition). More specifically, your problem is geared towards image-analysis, dealing mainly in [Template Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching):

> Template matching is a technique in digital image processing for
>   finding small parts of an image which match a template image. It can
>   be used in manufacturing as a part of quality control, a way to
>   navigate a mobile robot, or as a way to detect edges in images.

**The Template Matching page has a C-like language sample algorithm which demonstrates what you are attempting to do (identify a specific color within an image).**

As for how to go about this, generally speaking you will have to load an image, store it into an array then try to manipulate it as the algorithm suggests:

> One way to perform template matching on color images is to decompose
>   the pixels into their color components and measure the quality of
>   match between the color template and search image using the sum of the
>   absolute differences (SAD) computed for each color separately.

Of course, there are numerous projects in various languages that do that for you. **My suggestion is to read up a bit more on the topic, pick a language, and attempt a solution using libraries as necessary.**

One book that you might find to be very helpful is the classic [Phillips: Image Processing in C](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/) even if you don't want to use C. Why? Because it pores over a lot of the algorithmic details in how they work, and how to implement them. And, its free too.